# How to check if an app is running in iPhone emulation mode on iPad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios8

I'm creating a keyboard for iOS 8. I have two xib files. One for the iPad and one for the iPhone.

I load the appropriate xib file by checking UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM.

The problem is for an app that is designed for an iPhone but runs in emulation mode on iPad, wrong xib file is loaded and the layout is full of problems.

How can I check if the app is an iPhone app but running in emulation mode on iPad?

Comment: I'd assume that an app running in iPhone mode on an iPad should get an iPhone keyboard. Might want to file a bug with Apple.

Comment: @rickster Since I check the device the app is running on using UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad or ...Phone, the method returns the correct device but it is not aware of the emulation 1x/2x mode. Do you believe it's a bug?